# Any meaningful interpretation t-distribution, when rescaled using the sample SD?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, p-value, t-distribution, frequentist

To visualize p-values or confidence intervals, the t-distribution is sometimes rescaled using the sample standard deviation and then centered at a certain value.

To be more specific, consider drawing a random sample of size $n$ from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$. The random variables $M$ and $S$ denote the sample mean and sample standard deviation. Then $T=\frac{(M-\mu)\sqrt{n}}{S}$ has a t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

Let $m$ and $s$ denote the observed sample mean and standard deviation, and let $\mu_{L}$ and $\mu_U$ denote the limits of a 95% confidence interval for $\mu$. The confidence limits can be visualized by rescaling and relocating the t-distribution via $\frac{Ts}{\sqrt{n}}+\mu_L$ and $\frac{Ts}{\sqrt{n}}+\mu_U$.

Below is an example with $n=10$, $m \approx -0.46$ (solid vertical line), $s \approx 1.00$, $\mu_L\approx-1.18$ (left vertical dashed line), $\mu_U\approx0.25$ (right vertical dashed line). The area under the left curve above the vertical solid line is $0.025$, so is the area under the right curve below the certical solid line.

Do these distributions have any meaningful interpretation?

[image]

(My intuition says no, and it might be more appropriate to stay in the "standardized mean difference space" when visualizing this, since then you could say "assuming $\mu=\mu_0$, this is how the quantity $\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{s}$ would be distributed in the long run, etc.)

Code to reproduce the figure:

```r
set.seed(12)
x <- rnorm(10)
m <- mean(x)
s <- sd(x)

print(m)
print(s)

ci <- m + qt(c(0.025, 0.975), n-1) * s/sqrt(n)

xvec <- seq(-4, 4, 0.05)
dens <- dt(xvec, n-1) * sqrt(n)/s

lower_xvec <- xvec*s/sqrt(n) + ci[1]
upper_xvec <- xvec*s/sqrt(n) + ci[2]

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(0, 0, type="n", xlim=c(-1,1)*max(abs(lower_xvec), abs(upper_xvec)), ylim=(c(0, max(dens))), xlab="", ylab="")
abline(v=m)
abline(v=ci[1], lty="dashed")
abline(v=ci[2], lty="dashed")
lines(lower_xvec, dens)
lines(upper_xvec, dens)
```

Comment: Neither of the curves depicts a rescaled t-distribution: scaling will keep the distribution centered at zero.  This strange behavior, along with the meaningless label "x" on the horizontal axis, makes the figure and the question difficult to interpret.  Consider editing this post to clarify what you are doing.

Comment: I have added clarifications. The distributions scaled and relocated.

Comment: Thank you.  I still cannot make sense of it.  Perhaps that's because it looks like you use "$T$" in several different senses, as a test statistic and as a critical value.  Another is that you still haven't explained what these curves represent.

Comment: $T$ is the random variable with t-distribution. No mention of critical values anyhwere (of course they are used to compute the confidence interval, but I skipped that step). "What these curves represent" -- that is exactly my question. I don't think they represent anything really, which is why it does not make sense to visualize confidence interval this way, in this case. If the population SD was known, you could do the same with Z (standard normal) instead of T, and the distributions would represent the sampling distributions of $m$ given $\mu=\mu_L$ or $\mu=\mu_U$, which is meaningful.

Comment: In "The confidence limits can be visualized by," the values used to determine those limits are the critical values.